# rtsp live stream in android mediaplayer with Digest Authentication

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, live-streaming, digest-authentication

I need an android app to live stream rtsp url using videoview or media player with digest authentication. I don't know how to use digest authentication along with rtsp url. Is it possible using digest authentication in mediaplayer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's broken at present which is a major problem from my point of view since there appears to be no way to connect a stream directly to MediaPlayer either (that is, have some "shim" do that work for you, which might otherwise work -- and which would also make tunneling RTSP over an SSL connection at some remote site possible, resolving the "wide-open video" issue at the same time.)

The issue is that while the MediaPlayer will issue a digest for authentication on RTSP requests what it sends is broken -- specifically, there's an EXTRA SPACE at the end of the URI it passes back:

```
 D13.Denninger.Net.51291 > 192.168.4.211.rtsp: Flags [P.], cksum 0x069b (correct), seq 166:526, ack 143, win 256, length 360: RTSP, length: 360
    DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.4.211:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 RTSP/1.0
    Accept: application/sdp
    Authorization: Digest nonce="a2732278fba530ed26e2a278a866fa13", username="karl", uri="rtsp://192.168.4.211:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 ", response="311b3d4ea28e643ed0d7e61820d43588"
    User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 6.0)
    CSeq: 2
```

That space is NOT THERE in the actual URI passed to the Android Mediaplayer code and causes the authentication to fail.

There's an AOSP bug filed against this (which I contributed the above trace to with more details) but until and unless Google fixes it the only alternative is to find some other player that (1) works with RTSP and either (2) correctly handles digest authentication or (2a) can be attached to a socket allowing you to write a shim, either remotely or locally, to handle the digest work yourself.

I've yet to find one but would love a pointer if someone has resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly how to resolve the problem with RSTP mixed with disgest authentication.

But, Digest Authentication with HTTP using URLConnection.

There is this implementation that might be helpful for you.

https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5624590

Theoretically, after you have passed through the authentication process, you could get the data from the stream server and render it.